# CvtColor Error at higher resolutions

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, logitech

I have a Logitech Pro 9000 webcam and right now I try to learn OpenCV. I use OpenCV 2.4.5 together with Python 2.7. I'm having problems with the CvtColor function at higher resolutions. The following script is working in 640x480, but not with higher resolutions (800X600 and up).

```
import cv

cv.NamedWindow("Video", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

camera_index = 1
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(camera_index)
cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1200)
cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,800)

grey_frame = cv.CreateImage((1200,800),8,1)

while True:
    input_frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.CvtColor(input_frame,grey_frame,cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.WaitKey(5)
    cv.ShowImage("Video", grey_frame)
```

I get the following error

```
cv2.error: dst.data == dst0.data
```

EDIT: SOLVED After saving the captured input_frame. I noticed that the resolution of the saved image is not matching my set values. I set 1200x800 as capture properties and got a 1280x800 image. After using this resolution, everything worked fine.

Comment: What is your original camera resolution? I think you are not allowed to set capture properties height & width higher than original values. Instead of 1200x800, the capture property might have been set to the camera resolution limit. Then that shoud be why you are getting a size mismatch for the cvtcolor function.

Comment: The maximum resolution of the camera is 1600x800. I tested the resolution in OpenCV. cv.ShowOmage("Video", input_frame) will work in the above code. It is cv.CvtColor, that has a problem with the higher resolutions.

Comment: can you debug and see if the input_frame is 8bitdepth 3 channels or not?

Answer (score 0):

After saving the captured input_frame. I noticed that the resolution of the saved image is not matching my set values. I set 1200x800 as capture properties and got a 1280x800 image. After using this resolution, everything worked fine.